# ActiveRecord::Associations::Collection to Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a collection:

```
<Vote id: nil, author_uid: 9326214>,
<Vote id: nil, author_uid: 5643421>,
<Vote id: nil, author_uid: 9753813>
```

How can I get an array of author_uid values?

Thanks!

Comment: accept the `answer` a tick mark to the left-side of answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Vote.all.pluck(:author_uid)
```

[Ruby on Rails Guide - pluck](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck)